# Dialogflow: Agent Name (Project ID) - What characters are allowed?

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, invalid-characters

What characters are allowed in the name of a Dialogflow agent?

I can't create an agent right now where I can find out what characters are allowed, because I reached my maximum number of agents on my account, and should not delete one, as all the agents I have are for work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agent names in Dialogflow can contain:

Alphanumeric (examples: "a", "A", "1")

Special characters (examples: "!", "{", "'")

To test this, I created a Dialogflow agent named:

aA1`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{\|;:'",<.>/?

No errors.

It looks to me like the only characters you can't use are white space characters. So, the spacebar, tab, or enter.

Hope that helps.

Be careful not to confuse the Dialog Agent name with your Actions on Google project ID. I've attached a screenshot of where you find your Actions project ID (at actions.google.com):

[How to find your Project ID (imgur link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vN9n.png)

Comment: Thank you very much! :)